# Tried installing Fedora alongside Windows 10 - No Operating System Found

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, fedora, boot-partition, system-recovery

So, I installed Fedora on a live USB and tried installing it to my PC. I think I somehow messed up the ESP boot partition and whenever I start my computer it says "no operating system found". I can still access the live USB from my BIOS and when I check my files, they are all still intact.
Now, I have two questions:-
1) Is there a way to delete files from my hard drive, it is read-only right now and is it possible to change that?
2)Is there a possibility of creating a recovery image of my Windows partition(C: drive) and back it up to a D: drive or a complete separate harddisk that i have? If there is, how do I proceed after that? What do I do to fix the boot stuff without losing the files in my D: drive which doesn't have the Windows Operating System.
Some technical specs:-
Running Fedora 28 Workstation
Windows 10 OS
1 TB HDD
Windows Operating System drive size 60 GB(Could be reduced to around 50 if I could delete files from it)
D: drive - 560 GB free space
Separate harddisk - 120 GB
Edit:
Size of live USB running Fedora shows 6.8 GB with 1 GB free but it is actually a 16 GB USB stick. 
Some screenshots:
[When booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkP9M.jpg)
[After trying to install Fedora once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUMSz.jpg)
[The partitioning scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhSfN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue stems from the fact that your `/dev/sda2` is TOO small for both Windows and Fedora EFI bits.

Some background info:

The average Windows 'kernel'  is 75Mb  in size and a default 'just works' Fedora kernel is 25-28M, simple math shows 100-105M > 99M.

If I understood your `2)Is there a possibility of creating a recovery image of my Windows partition(C: drive) and back it up to a D: drive or a complete separate hard disk that i have?` question correctly you'd need either:

1) enough spare drive space to hold roughly 300Gb to contain ALL of the present Windows and Fedora data.

2) enough space (noticeably smaller restraint) for the non-os data on Windows and Fedora respectively

At which point I'd recommend starting the partitioning logic from scratch with the following minimal partitioning:

---

**(Windows ESP/MSR)**

/dev/sda1   450M

**BOOT/EFI**

*(Enough for Windows kernel and the default 3 kernels held but grub)*

/dev/sda2 100M or better (256M is common)

**(Windows ESP/MSR)**

/dev/sda3 16M

**(Windows C:)**

/dev/sda4 116.8G

**(Windows D: (possible Shared Drive across both OSes)**

*(CAUTION: This drive Should NOT be reformatted during reinstall, nor does it need reformatting; unless all precious data is copied/backed up somewhere)*

/dev/sda5 661.8G

**(Fedora 28 -- Using Default LVM)**

/dev/sda6  144.3G

**(Fedora Swap)**

*Should ideally be part of the sda6 lvm*

/dev/sda7  8G

---